# É válido traduzir uma resposta do StackOverflow em inglês?

Tags: debate, tradução, stackoverflow

Por vezes já vi perguntas aqui no StackOverflow em português que já foram feitas no StackOverflow em inglês. Nem sempre as perguntas são feitas pelo mesmo usuário e nem sempre a pergunta é exatamente a mesma, mas em muitos casos a resposta feita na versão em inglês se aplica totalmente para a pergunta em português.

Qual seria a maneira ideal para lidar com esse caso? Penso em algumas abordagens:

1. Traduzir a resposta aceita, ou outra resposta cabível da versão em inglês
2. Tentar compreender as respostas em inglês e, somando os seus conhecimentos, elaborar uma resposta em português
3. Referenciar o link com a resposta em inglês (possivelmente com a tradução junto)
4. Não responder a questão se você não tiver conhecimento para tal. Particularmete, não gosto dessa sugestão, porque você estaria omitindo uma ajuda, mesmo sabendo que existe uma resposta para aquela pergunta.

Outras sugestões são bem vindas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Não existe regra nem maneira ideal. Tem uma boa resposta, em português? Poste! Quer traduzir um conteúdo externo que acha muito bom? Vá em frente, mas não se esqueça de citar a fonte.

Quanto ao seu item 4, eu evitaria responder com uma tradução se eu não tiver conhecimento do assunto, já que não tenho como julgar por conta própria se o conteúdo está correto ou não. Também não teria como responder a possíveis questionamentos do autor da pergunta ou de outros usuários. Mas note que isso não tem nada a ver com a resposta ser traduzida ou não, e sim com postar algo que você mesmo não entende.

Comment: Concordo com a parte de que eu não teria conhecimento para responder eventuais comentários. Entretanto, se há um conhecimento mínimo (mesmo que não haja domínio do assunto) de que aquela resposta realmente responde a pergunta feita, o fato de ela ter um bom número de votos positivos e ter sido aceita por quem perguntou no SO em inglês não a classificaria como uma boa resposta? Não traduzir não seria uma forma de evitar que o conhecimendo seja disseminado?

Comment: Eu entendo seu raciocínio, e esse é mais um ponto em que não há regra. Se quiser traduzir, pode traduzir (lembrando novamente: cite a fonte!). O que eu disse é que "eu evitaria" por não me sentir confortável em publicar algo que não compreendo direito. Se você se sente à vontade para fazer isso, tudo bem.

Comment: +1 para dar ênfase no "cite a fonte".

Comment: +1 pelo bom senso de evitar responder se não possuir conhecimento. E, se pudesse, colocaria outro +1 por expor a sua opinião e não impô-la. Obs.: Que estranha esta última conjugação verbal!