# Pode ser considerado duplicata perguntas de outros stackoverflow?

Tags: debate, suporte

Pode também ser considerado duplicata perguntas de outros stackoverflow sendo traduzidas para o SOpt?

Comment: Como assim traduzidas? Se ela é uma duplicata no SOpt, ela já não estaria em português?

Comment: Me parece relacionado: [É válido traduzir uma resposta do StackOverflow em inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/3774)

Comment: Não. Espero ter tirado todas as suas dúvidas.

Comment: Duplicada só o que já tem no site, o que estiver no escopo, ainda não constar aqui e houver uma igual em outro site não tem problema postar

Comment: Seria tipo assim. Eu peguei uma pergunta do Jon Skeet, traduzi ela e coloquei como minha no meu SOpt.

Comment: Que ironia, uma pergunta sobre perguntas duplicadas ser uma duplicada